# How do I attach a working pdf of my google sheet to a draft email?

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, format

I have a script that was put together to open, rename, and export a google sheet as a pdf. Then that sheet would be added to an email draft. I have been using this script for two years without issue, but for some reason, the pdf attachment will no longer open.

The error message I get is "Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open [File Name.pdf] because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged." I go directly to the google sheet and export as a pdf manually, I can open it without issue, so it is definitely tied to the script.

Could you please review the below script and see if there is a work around I can use?

```
 // Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side.
 // It is opened on the server only (for modification by the script).
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(Logger.getLog());
 var first = ss.getSheetByName("BHC AP Vendor Payment");
    var vendorname = first.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var paymentdate = first.getRange(2, 22).getDisplayValue();
 // renames the google sheet to the data that is in 2nd Row, 1st Column
  ss.rename('BHC '+vendorname+' Payment ['+paymentdate+']');
  
  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('BHC AP Vendor Payment'); //returns the sheet named 'BHC AP Vendor Payment'
  sheet.setName('BHC '+vendorname+' Payment ['+paymentdate+']');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //returns integer last row
  
    var url = ss.getUrl();

  //remove the trailing 'edit' from the url
  url = url.replace(/edit$/, '');

  //additional parameters for exporting the sheet as a pdf
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + //export as pdf
    //below parameters are optional...
    '&size=letter' + //paper size
    '&portrait=false' + //orientation, false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' + //fit to width, false for actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false' + //hide optional headers and footers
    '&gridlines=false' + //hide gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId(); //the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });

  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(ss.getName() + '.pdf');


     // Create a draft email with a file from Google Drive attached as a PDF.
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(*sample document*);
 var body = doc.getBody();
  var bodytext = body.getText();

  var apEmail = *sample email address*;
    var subject = 'Payment ['+vendorname+']';
   
  
  GmailApp.createDraft('', subject, bodytext, {
    cc: apEmail,
    from: apEmail,
        attachments: [blob
        ]
```

Thank you!

Comment: In your situation, when `blob` of `var blob = response.getBlob().setName(ss.getName() + '.pdf')` is created as a PDF file, is the created PDF file correct PDF file you expect?

Comment: When I look at the email draft with the attachment, it reads as ".pdf" and when I save it to my computer in order to open the file, it is listed as a pdf in the properties.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I cannot understand about `The error message I get is "Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open [File Name.pdf] because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged."`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: Thank you for your question. 

When I run the script, I successfully get an email draft with a pdf attachment. However, when I download that pdf attachment and try to open it, I get an error message. 

If I try to open it in Google Chrome, the error message is "Failed to load PDF document." If I try to open it in Adobe Acrobat Reader, I get the error message "Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open [File Name.pdf] because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged."

Does that make more sense? If not, I can find another way to explain the issue.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that your issue had already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modifications:

Could you please try the following two modification points:

- Instead of:

  ```
  url = url.replace(/edit$/, '');
  ```

  use:

  ```
  url = url.replace(/\/edit.*$/, '');
  ```

---

- and instead of:

  ```
  var url_ext = 'export?...'
  ```

  use:

  ```
  var url_ext = '/export?...'
  ```

---

### Full code:

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(Logger.getLog());
 var first = ss.getSheetByName("BHC AP Vendor Payment");
    var vendorname = first.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var paymentdate = first.getRange(2, 22).getDisplayValue();
 // renames the google sheet to the data that is in 2nd Row, 1st Column
  ss.rename('BHC '+vendorname+' Payment ['+paymentdate+']');
  
  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('BHC AP Vendor Payment'); //returns the sheet named 'BHC AP Vendor Payment'
  sheet.setName('BHC '+vendorname+' Payment ['+paymentdate+']');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //returns integer last row
  


  //remove the trailing 'edit' from the url
  url = url.replace(/\/edit.*$/, '');


  //additional parameters for exporting the sheet as a pdf
  var url_ext = '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + //export as pdf
    //below parameters are optional...
    '&size=letter' + //paper size
    '&portrait=false' + //orientation, false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' + //fit to width, false for actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false' + //hide optional headers and footers
    '&gridlines=false' + //hide gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId(); //the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });

  var blob = response.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(ss.getName() + '.pdf');


     // Create a draft email with a file from Google Drive attached as a PDF.
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(*sample document*);
 var body = doc.getBody();
  var bodytext = body.getText();

  var apEmail = *sample email address*;
    var subject = 'Payment ['+vendorname+']';
   
  
  GmailApp.createDraft('', subject, bodytext, {
    cc: apEmail,
    from: apEmail,
        attachments: [blob
        ]})
```

Comment: Another option would be the following: `url = url.replace(/\/edit.*$/, '');` and `var url_ext = '/export?...'`.

Comment: @Iamblichus thanks for the recommendation, I will give some time to the OP to try my answer and then I will update it to include yours. Thanks again !

Comment: @Marios I tried replacing the segments you referred to above, but unfortunately when I ran the script, I no longer received an email draft in gmail.

Comment: can you just try one of them only? either the first or the second modification alone. @MeredithMiller

Comment: Ok I tried your solution, @Marios and unfortunately it didn't create a draft, either with both changes or just trying one individually. Good news is that the idea lamblichus had worked! I can now download the pdf and it will open without issue. I really appreciate the work you both put into this! You are both great! Thank you!